# Как распределить тестовые случаи по разным файлам в unittest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, юнит-тесты, python-unittest

Есть директория `tests`, в ней находятся файл `__init__.py` и несколько файлов `*_test.py`, в каждом таком файле находится от одного класса - тестового случая. Как сделать так, чтобы выполнив `__init__.py` выполнились все тестовые случаи в файлах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) поддерживает управление через командную строку.

Просто надо написать команду ниже, не заходя в директорию tests, ниже показан пример запуска всех тестов на библиотеке bs4.

```
python -m unittest
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]